# $f'$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ be a bounded connected subset in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a differentiable function.

Does boundedness of $f'$ imply boundedness of $f$?

(I edited this post after I realized that I didn't actually write what i wanted, after i saw Gautam's post.)

Comment: Bounded interval would have sufficed. I'll edit my answer after some thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean by interval a *bounded* interval, then the answer is yes because of the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). If not then the identity function provides a counterexample.

*Added explanation* of the bounded interval case. We may assume (by adding a constant which does not affect boundedness of $f$ and even less that of $f'$) that $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in I$. The interval has some finite length $l$, and the mean value theorem implies that whenever $|f(x)|>lC$ for some $C$ then there exists $x'\in I$ such that $|f'(x')|=\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-x_0|}>C$, so that if $f$ is unbounded, $f'$ must also be unbounded.

Comment: Yes i meant this. I know mean value theorem, but i don't know how to derive boundedness of $f$.Would you help?

Comment: The mean value theorem he is referring to is the Lagrange's MVT. Before that, Rolle's MVT is derived and Lagrange's MVT is a special case of it.

Comment: @GautamShenoy: Your comment confuses me. The link I provided makes perfectly clear which theorem I'm referring to, and I would say that Rolle's theorem is a special case of it (which does not exclude it being used in a proof of the MVT) rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Marc: You are right. What I meant was, Rolle's theorem was independently proved. And by a clever substitution, you get the generalization that is Lagrange MVT. If you see the proof, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It's great. Thank you

Comment: How do i delete this comment

Comment: @Kaltus: When you hoover the mouse over your own name at the end of a comment, a cross appears to the right of it; clicking that will delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider f(x)=x. Over $\mathbb{R}$, it is unbounded but the derivative is constant(and hence bounded). However if you take a finite interval (or an interval contained in a compact set), then the function will be bounded NOT because the derivative is bounded but because the function is continuous.

Edit: I stand corrected. Given continuity and an open interval, a function can be unbounded. Differentiability, same story. Bounded derivative on the other hand will indeed imply boundedness of the function.

Comment: Intervals can be open, and continous functions on them unbounded (think $\tan$ on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$).

Comment: Same goes for differentiable functions. Additionally tan does not have a bounded derivative.

Comment: @Marc: If a function is differentiable in I, I is open and if it is unbounded, like your example, can it have a bounded derivative?

Comment: My first comment was (only) because you wrote "the function will be bounded NOT because the derivative is bounded but because the function is continuous". Answering your second comment, a function with bounded derivative on a bounded interval will be bounded, see my answer.

Comment: @Gautam Would you give me another example? I know it is a theorem that if $I$ is compact and $f$ is continuous,then $f(I)$ is bounded. What if domain of $f$ is $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is bounded? ($-\infty<a<b<\infty$)

Comment: The theorem is correct. Moreover f(I) is compact. Look at it in this way. Let the derivative be bdd by M. Then your entire function from a to b lies within $f(a) \pm Mt$.

Comment: @Gautam I think that's true only when $a$ is in the domain. Would you check my edited post

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. To fix it, pick $c \in (a,b)$. Now use my idea to show that the function cannot escape similar clutches with bdd derivative.